# Google Drive Public API access

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I need the server of my webapp to be able to create a spreadsheet in a Drive folder without any user intervention.

Is this possible using the Public API access key I created in the APIs & auth section of the developers console?

Something like this:

```
    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(apiAccessKey);

    client = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(name);
    body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
    body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference()
            .setId(folder)));

    File file = client.files().insert(body).execute();
    return file.getId();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you need to create a serviceaccount and then it is easy. Remember to add the Drive scope to the application in the google security console: https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#OGX:ManageOauthClients

```
private static final String USER_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xxxx";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xxxx";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "/src/main/resources/xxxx";
private Drive getDriveService()
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
    scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountUser(USER_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
            .build();
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
    return service;
}

@Override
public String createBlankSheet(String name, String folder)
        throws Exception {

    Drive client = getDriveService();

    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(name);
    body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

    File file = client.files().insert(body).execute();
    return file.getId();
}
```